# Business Class unable to reference HTTPContext

Tags: c#

I have a Business Layer set up as another C# project within my solution, I need to call HttpContext but no matter what  I try I cannot get it to reference correctly.

I have tried getting Visual Studio to pick up the reference needed with no luck, and I have also tried putting a reference to **System.Web** manually but these do not seems to work.

I have also noticed that **Session** is not being found as well.

Below is the code snippet I've used

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace BussinessLayer
{
    class UserPermissions
    {
        public void redirectToLogin()
        {

            if (Session["user"] == null)
            {
                HttpContext.
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["userName"] == null)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/login.aspx");
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know whay HttpContext or Session are not being found?

Comment: When you say "reference" - do you mean you're getting a compiler error?  Or is HttpContext.Current coming back as null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to do with targeting the *.NET 4 Client Profile*. You'll be able to fix this by retargeting your project to the full *.NET Framework 4*.

Answer (score 2):

HttpContext.Current not suit for bussiness layer, you can use [HttpContextBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) instead

```
    public static class HttpContextHelper {
    private static object lockObj = new object();
    private static HttpContextBase mockHttpContext;

    /// <summary>
    /// Access the HttpContext using the Abstractions.
    /// </summary>
    public static HttpContextBase Current {
        get {
            lock (lockObj) {
                if (mockHttpContext == null && HttpContext.Current != null) {
                    return new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
                }
            }

            return mockHttpContext;
        }

        set {
            lock (lockObj) {
                mockHttpContext = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference System.Web.dll which can be found in GAC (My VS2010 doesn't show it in '.NET References' so I had to add it by hand).

Also if you're separating business layer it may be wise to to it more independent, more loosely-coupled.

Answer (score 1):

You really, truly, honestly should *not* need to reference `HttpContext` from your business layer.  If you do, then it's no longer a business layer.  It's part of the presentation layer with a hard-coded dependency to the presentation engine.

Whatever value is needed from `HttpContext` should be supplied to the business layer object when called by the presentation layer.