# Reading an RTF file inside a business logic (DLL) referenced from ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, webforms, rtf, activereports

How do you read a file inside a business logic (DLL) located in that project where it is referenced from an ASP.NET application ?

Here my scenario, i have a web application then a library which load activereport reports that produce pdf. One of that report have a RichText control which load from a file.. i tried to make it load from a resource file but only the first line of the RTF was shown and i really wonder why... so my next attempt was to open the file on the server.. but i don't have access to Server.MapPath because i am on a business logic. What are my others options ?

Thanks!

Comment: could you share the rtf string that is being read from resource?  What lines of code are you using to read assign the rtf to rtb control?

Comment: Can't its confidential sorry. I tried to put the file in a resource file and then assign this to the RTF propertie of the control.

Comment: It seems the error is reading in the resource stream. You can most definitely read data from a resource stream and use that in an RTF control in AR. Please post the code you're using to read from the resource stream and we can help you debug that code.

Comment: have you figured this out yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reference to the Server object via the HttpContext, but it is less than desirable because now you have made your business layer dependent upon the presentation layer.

See [Bussiness Class unable to refrence HTTPContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315455/bussiness-class-unable-to-refrence-httpcontext)

Comment: Offcourse this is not desirable. Would it be possible to load it from assembly application start ?

Comment: Are you trying to stream a file (PDF) to the browser?

Comment: You should consider using an HTTP Handler (.ashx) that will call to your library and get the PDF, then return the PDF to the browser (as an attachment so it will stream and the browser will use the MIME type to have the client figure out how to open it).

Comment: Its not so simple, i can't change the way things are configured this is a company application problem i have to solve and i can't touch the way the pdf are rendered. :)